# How can I make images rows scale inside div

Tags: html, css

I want to crop images that are in row, when the window width gets smaller, the images scale down without one image piling on top of another.
I want the images be in each row in pairs and prevent them piling vertically when window crops.

```css
.row {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px;
}
.container img {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg?hmac=TmmQSbShHz9CdQm0NkEjx1Dyh_Y984R9LpNrpvH2D_U"></img>
        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg?hmac=TmmQSbShHz9CdQm0NkEjx1Dyh_Y984R9LpNrpvH2D_U"></img>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg?hmac=TmmQSbShHz9CdQm0NkEjx1Dyh_Y984R9LpNrpvH2D_U"></img>
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg?hmac=TmmQSbShHz9CdQm0NkEjx1Dyh_Y984R9LpNrpvH2D_U"></img>
  </div>
</div>
</body>



</html>
```

[before the window width scale down, images are big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaSOO.png)

[after browser width gets smaller, images stay in pairs in horizontal rows and scale down proportionally.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgWjW.png)

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: no, I would prefer not using it

Comment: Try adding display: flex; to the .row class if you are not using bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the below code in your style.css file.

```
.row {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px;
}
.container img {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 558px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .container img {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 42vw;
  }
}
```